# No member name in namespace 'block-signing_authority' in eosio

Tags: eosio-code, eosio.system

I am having issues compling the eosio.system contract with the new eosio 2.0 upgrades I keep generating the same error  below. What could be the cause of this error ?

include/eosio.system/eosio.system.hpp:186:18: error: no type
      named 'block_signing_authority' in namespace 'eosio'
   inline eosio::block_signing_authority convert_to_block...

Answer (score 0):

You need the latest version of eosio.cdt (currently [v1.7.0](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/releases/tag/v1.7.0)) to build eosio.contracts.

eosio 2.0 now supports WTMsig, weighted threshold multi-signature authorities for block production, so eosio.system contract will take `block_signing_authority` type for block production schedule instead of `producer_key` type.

Answer (score 0):

I have the latest version that I am using but I am still running into this issue when I try to compile and deploy the eosio.system contract.